# Skip values of field already counted in sub cardinality aggregation elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a alert index in elastic with fields severity and sourceId. This basically represents a alert from a source with sourceId and severity(critical,major,minor) at any given time.
Now I want to find count of sourceIds per severity.
This can be done by aggregating on severity and sub cardinality aggregation on sourceIds. But I want to exclude sourceId if its already counted in "critical" bucket.
Is there any way to do so.My elastic query is as follows:

```
GET alert/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "keywise_alert_severity": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "severity"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "keyGroupingAggr": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "sourceId"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible directly because elasticsearch would have to run a search query for each document to detect if the `sourceId` is found in a document with critical severity. However, what you could do is add a filter aggregation and count the number of source with severity `critical`. You can then just substract the two values to get the correct result.

Comment: @Pierre-NicolasMougel Thanks for the reply.. I also researched and think that its not possible to get distinct cardanility for each bucket. I will try if some workaround works.